# What is the dsCorePropagation attribute and why does my script use it?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I have a script where I'm querying the LastLogonTimeStamp attribute and deleting accounts on two conditions, one being that they belong to two security groups, and the other being that they have not logged on to a computer in 75 days. Below is my script:

```
$75DayExemptGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity "AccountComplianceExemption_75DayLimit" | Select -exp DistinguishedName
$AccountInactvityGroupMembers = Get-ADGroup -Identity "AccountComplianceExemption_AccountInactivity" -Properties Members | Select -ExpandProperty Members

foreach ($UserDN in $AccountInactvityGroupMembers) {
$fullADUser = Get-ADUser $UserDN -properties LastLogonTimeStamp,MemberOf,Description,CanonicalName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*MAB_Devices*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Mailboxes*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*AFG TNOSC*" -and $_.Name -notlike "svc.*" -and $_.Name -notlike "grp.*"}
if ($fullADUser.MemberOf -like "*$75DayExemptGroup*") {
    $LastLogonDate = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($fullADUser.LastLogonTimeStamp)
    $75Days = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-75)
    if ($LastLogonDate -lt $75Days -and $fullADUser.LastLogonTimeStamp -ne $null) 
    {
        $OrigDesc = $fullADuser.Description
        $OUPath = $fullADuser.CanonicalName
        $NewDesc = "Deleted by JNCC-A for 75 days of inactivity - Original Desc [$OrigDesc] - OU: $OUPath"
        Set-ADUser $fullADuser -Description $NewDesc
        if ($?) {Remove-ADUser $fullADUser -Confirm $false}
    }
    $LastLogonDate = ""
    }
}
```

So I run the script, right? There are 3 users that are in both groups, right? Then there is one user that is below the 75 day mark, one that is above the 75 day mark, and then one that has never logged in and thus shows "`<not set`>" in the AD object. Now, when my script compares the $LastLogonDate variable for the user has never logged on, it shows the date "January 1, 1601 4:30:00 AM". Now, I figure this is some sort of default when the value is null or 0 I guess, but I looked closer at the ADUC object and it shows that date in the "dsCorePropagation" attribute when I query it in Powershell, it shows the date, but when I look at that attribute on the AD object, it contains the hex code for "0".

My script works as it is because I compare $fullADUser.LastLogonTimeStamp to null, I just thought it would be interesting to get more perspective as to why the $LastLogonDate variable isn't null because $fullADUser.LastLogonTimeStamp is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because System.DateTime is a non nullable type, so if you pass FromFileTime a null or zero value, it will just return the minimum FileTime value, which is 01/01/1601

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> [datetime]::FromFileTime($null)
01 January 1601 00:00:00
```

If you want a DateTime to be nullable, you must use [Nullable DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253519.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I did some more research and finally made sense of out it. Thanks!